# Json Ajax PHP is NULL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, null

I get an array with the geolocation JavaScript, then I want to pass this array to a php script via ajax to process it and get an processed array back. Unfortunately it seems that the passed array to php is always NULL, I have no idea why.

My JavaScript/jQuery:

```
dataArray = [];
        var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
        dataArray.push({'lat':lat});
        var lon = pos.coords.longitude;
        dataArray.push({'lon':lon});
        var identifier = 'ajax';
        dataArray.push({'identifier':identifier});
        console.debug(dataArray);

        $.ajax({
                async:   true,
                type:        'post',
                cache:       false,
                url:         'custom.php',
                data:        {myJson: dataArray},
                dataType   : 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.debug(data);
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    console.debug(json);
                    alert(json);
                }
        });
```

My php:

```
$JSArray['array'] = json_decode($_POST['myJson'], true);
$_SESSION['jsonArray'] = $JSArray['array'];
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

The result is always `["jsonArray"]=> NULL`.

Comment: why you use JSON.stringify ?

Comment: well, I'm new to ajax/json and I thought I have to stringify an array before I can pass it to php. But please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Its not needed. 
remove that line and try to var_dump($_POST) to check what goes to your PHP..

Comment: You could attempt to var_dump entire $_POST variable to see what the raw data is (better yet the $_REQUEST variable which is a combination between $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE - it's useful for debugging but should be avoided in sharp code).

Comment: the $_POST variable is also empty  array(0) { } }, also with stringify removed

Comment: Not sure what the answer to your question is yet, but the $.parseJson line in your success callback should also be removed. Since you told jQuery the data type is JSON it will do the parsing for you as soon as you get the server to have a valid JSON response.

Comment: Try changing 'type' to 'get', have the PHP use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST and navigate to the PHP page directly with some test data, e.g. custom.php?myJson=[{lat:1}]. Or just analayze the request/reponse in Firebug. Also I don't think dataArray should be an array of objects, just make it a single object and use lat, lon, etc. as the keys

Comment: Thank you all, I think I got it. As far as I see it, the main Problem was, that the values passed for lat and lon were numbers, but json needed a string. So I used (pos.coords.latitude).toString(); and now it seems to work. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working...although numbers shouldn't have caused an issue; maybe pos.coords.latitude is an object that evaluates to a string with the latitude number when you call toString on it.

Comment: Also, when sending the response it's a best practice to add this before you echo the Json in PHP: header('Content-type: application/json'); This makes your app more secure.

Comment: Ok, I added the header('Content-type: application/json'); right before the echo statement. Thank you for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this one. it works for me

```
 (function($){
if(navigator.geolocation){return;}
var domWrite = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            throw('document.write is overwritten by geolocation shim. This method is incompatible with this plugin');
        }, 1);
    },
    id = 0
;
var geoOpts = $.webshims.cfg.geolocation.options || {};
navigator.geolocation = (function(){
    var pos;
    var api = {
        getCurrentPosition: function(success, error, opts){
            var locationAPIs = 2,
                errorTimer,
                googleTimer,
                calledEnd,
                endCallback = function(){
                    if(calledEnd){return;}
                    if(pos){
                        calledEnd = true;
                        success($.extend({timestamp: new Date().getTime()}, pos));
                        resetCallback();
                        if(window.JSON && window.sessionStorage){
                            try{
                                sessionStorage.setItem('storedGeolocationData654321', JSON.stringify(pos));
                            } catch(e){}
                        }
                    } else if(error && !locationAPIs) {
                        calledEnd = true;
                        resetCallback();
                        error({ code: 2, message: "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE"});
                    }
                },
                googleCallback = function(){
                    locationAPIs--;
                    getGoogleCoords();
                    endCallback();
                },
                resetCallback = function(){
                    $(document).unbind('google-loader', resetCallback);
                    clearTimeout(googleTimer);
                    clearTimeout(errorTimer);
                },
                getGoogleCoords = function(){
                    if(pos || !window.google || !google.loader || !google.loader.ClientLocation){return false;}
                    var cl = google.loader.ClientLocation;
                    pos = {
                        coords: {
                            latitude: cl.latitude,
                            longitude: cl.longitude,
                            altitude: null,
                            accuracy: 43000,
                            altitudeAccuracy: null,
                            heading: parseInt('NaN', 10),
                            velocity: null
                        },
                        //extension similiar to FF implementation
                        address: $.extend({streetNumber: '', street: '', premises: '', county: '', postalCode: ''}, cl.address)
                    };
                    return true;
                },
                getInitCoords = function(){
                    if(pos){return;}
                    getGoogleCoords();
                    if(pos || !window.JSON || !window.sessionStorage){return;}
                    try{
                        pos = sessionStorage.getItem('storedGeolocationData654321');
                        pos = (pos) ? JSON.parse(pos) : false;
                        if(!pos.coords){pos = false;} 
                    } catch(e){
                        pos = false;
                    }
                }
            ;

            getInitCoords();

            if(!pos){
                if(geoOpts.confirmText && !confirm(geoOpts.confirmText.replace('{location}', location.hostname))){
                    if(error){
                        error({ code: 1, message: "PERMISSION_DENIED"});
                    }
                    return;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://freegeoip.net/json/',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    cache: true,
                    jsonp: 'callback',
                    success: function(data){
                        locationAPIs--;
                        if(!data){return;}
                        pos = pos || {
                            coords: {
                                latitude: data.latitude,
                                longitude: data.longitude,
                                altitude: null,
                                accuracy: 43000,
                                altitudeAccuracy: null,
                                heading: parseInt('NaN', 10),
                                velocity: null
                            },
                            //extension similiar to FF implementation
                            address: {
                                city: data.city,
                                country: data.country_name,
                                countryCode: data.country_code,
                                county: "",
                                postalCode: data.zipcode,
                                premises: "",
                                region: data.region_name,
                                street: "",
                                streetNumber: ""
                            }
                        };
                        endCallback();
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        locationAPIs--;
                        endCallback();
                    }
                });
                clearTimeout(googleTimer);
                if (!window.google || !window.google.loader) {
                    googleTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                        //destroys document.write!!!
                        if (geoOpts.destroyWrite) {
                            document.write = domWrite;
                            document.writeln = domWrite;
                        }
                        $(document).one('google-loader', googleCallback);
                        $.webshims.loader.loadScript('http://www.google.com/jsapi', false, 'google-loader');
                    }, 800);
                } else {
                    locationAPIs--;
                }
            } else {
                setTimeout(endCallback, 1);
                return;
            }
            if(opts && opts.timeout){
                errorTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    resetCallback();
                    if(error) {
                        error({ code: 3, message: "TIMEOUT"});
                    }
                }, opts.timeout);
            } else {
                errorTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                    locationAPIs = 0;
                    endCallback();
                }, 10000);
            }
        },
        clearWatch: $.noop
    };
    api.watchPosition = function(a, b, c){
        api.getCurrentPosition(a, b, c);
        id++;
        return id;
    };
    return api;
})();

$.webshims.isReady('geolocation', true);
    })(jQuery);


     jQuery(window).ready(function(){ 

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,errorCallback,{timeout:10000});

function successCallback(pos) {

    $('#localstore').
    load("geo?latitude="+ pos.coords.latitude +"&longitude=" + pos.coords.longitude, function() 
    {
        $('#storefinder').hide();
        $('#localstore').show();
    });

}
function errorCallback(pos) {
    /*      
    $('#storefinder').show();
    $('#localstore').hide();
    */
}



});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple points are which your script can be failing.
I would test each step and see where it fails (by commenting out the echo statments one at a time):

```
echo $_POST['myJson'];
$JSArray['array'] = json_decode($_POST['myJson'], true);
//echo $JSArray['array'];
$_SESSION['jsonArray'] = $JSArray['array'];
//var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Also you ajax call should contain `alert(data)` without parseJSON, since the server is not sending JSON back, it is just echoing out a var_dump:

```
$.ajax({
                async:   true,
                type:        'post',
                cache:       false,
                url:         'custom.php',
                data:        {myJson: dataArray},
                dataType   : 'html', // change back to json when you send json from server
                success: function(data){
                    console.debug(data);
                    //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //console.debug(json);
                    //alert(json);
                    alert(data);
                }
        });
```

Comment: If you need to send lots of data from your PHP page, then you need to do a 'echo json_encode($array);' to send the data encoded via json.

Comment: I'm not sure alert(data) will do anything unless you temporarily change 'dataType' to 'html', but I could be wrong...

Comment: Unless of course you add the json_encode line to the PHP as Husman just mentioned, to make it valid Json. But raw text might be easier for debugging until you get the request to PHP correctly.

Comment: You are correct, that has to be set to html for this to work, i'll edit my answer for now.